# Edit mode for custom UITableViewCell with drawRect

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UITableViewCell subclass with this drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (self.checked)
    {
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake([self.contentView bounds].origin.x + 10, 12.0, 22, 22)];
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when the cell goes into edit mode and the drawn image doesn't move to the right like the UITextField and accessory views do. Instead the image becomes hidden by the delete button. How can I get the drawn image to animate to the right?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your cell to redraw itself when entering editing mode. Usually all it will do is resize the content view, which won't cause your checkmark to be redrawn.

However, to *animate* this is a little harder since you are directly drawing the check mark. You could try directly drawing it in the content view instead, or adding a subview to the content view which contains the checkmark - this will get moved automatically.

You could even use the built in image view, it seems to be in approximately the right position?

Comment: I used the built in image view and it animates just like the built in textfield. Thanks! I think you're right that drawing into the contentView would have done the trick too but with my own contentView I would lose the built in text field. Good to remember for when I need a flat cell with drawn content only (for speed). Not necessary for the table in question tho.